# How to compare arrays (not exact matches)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

So far I've been comparing arrays to a single variable e.g. the player position:

```
for position in ships:
    if player_location_x > position[0]-100 and player_location_x < position[0]+100 and player_location_y > position[1]-100 and player_location_y < position[1]+100:
        #Do something (e.g. draw bullets between the two locations)
```

How would I extend this to comparing the values of arrays themselves e.g. comparing the x and y values of 'ships' to check their distance to each other, and also comparing the x and y values between 'ships' and 'more_ships'?

```
ships = numpy.array([
                                [
                                  shuttle_class.npc_x[0],  
                                  shuttle_class.npc_y[0],  
                                  shuttle_class.img,    
                                  shuttle_class.hp
                                ],

                                [
                                  shuttle_class.npc_x[1],  
                                  shuttle_class.npc_y[1],  
                                  shuttle_class.img,    
                                  shuttle_class.hp
                                ],

                                [
                                  shuttle_class.npc_x[2],  
                                  shuttle_class.npc_y[2],  
                                  shuttle_class.img,    
                                  shuttle_class.hp
                                ]
                    ])

more_ships = numpy.array([
                                [
                                  shuttle_class.npc_x[3],  
                                  shuttle_class.npc_y[3],  
                                  shuttle_class.img,    
                                  shuttle_class.hp
                                ],

                                [
                                  shuttle_class.npc_x[4],  
                                  shuttle_class.npc_y[4],  
                                  shuttle_class.img,    
                                  shuttle_class.hp
                                ],

                                [
                                  shuttle_class.npc_x[5],  
                                  shuttle_class.npc_y[5],  
                                  shuttle_class.img,    
                                  shuttle_class.hp
                                ]
                         ])
```

Comment: One improvement you could make is by using quadtrees, so that every time something moves, you recalculate its position, which is quite cheap, then to check the distance, you only need to check the objects that are in the same grid section as you are. There might be a better way with numpy, but for the way you've currently done it, I know from doing it before that it gives a huge speed increase :)

Comment: Do I understand your question correctly: you have ships (arrays x1, y1) and more_ships (arrays x2, y2) and you want pairwise `x1-x2` and `y1-y2` for each possible combination?

Comment: @VBB Yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with two arrays `x1, y1` for ships. You want to generate each pairwise distance with `x2, y2`. Let's say for discussion sake that you have 5 ships and 3 more_ships. So we use numpy meshgrid:

```
xx1, xx2 = np.meshgrid(x1, x2)  # both these are 3x5 arrays
yy1, yy2 = np.meshgrid(y1, y2)
dx = xx1 - xx2 # np.abs(xx1 - xx2) if you want just absolute values
dy = yy1 - yy2
```

Now you can use `np.where` to get your final list:

```
sel = np.where( (dx <= d_max) & (dy <= d_max) )
```

sel is a 2xn array. The values are indices of the `n` points satisfying the condition.

---

**EDIT: adding sample code as requested by OP.**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

sx = np.array([0, 250, 500])
sy = np.array([100, 100, 100])
mx = np.array([1000, 0])
my = np.array([0,0])
plt.scatter(sx, sy)
plt.scatter(mx, my, c='r', marker='o')
plt.grid()
```

We have three ships (`s`), and two more_ships (`m`).

```
xx1, xx2 = np.meshgrid(sx, mx)
yy1, yy2 = np.meshgrid(sy, my)
```

Let us examine this a bit: `np.shape(xx1)` is `(2,3)`. The first index refers to `m` (more ships), and the second refers to `s`.

```
dx = np.abs(xx1 - xx2)
dy = np.abs(yy1 - yy2)
d_max = 200.0
sel = np.where( (dx <= d_max) & (dy <= d_max) )
print sel
```

You will see that sel has two arrays. The first array refers to indices for the first axis (`m`), and the second refers to (`s`). In this case, the arrays have values `1` and `0`, which means `more_ships[1]` is within 200 pixels of `ships[0]`.

If you change `sx` to `np.array([0, 250, 1000])` then `sel` will be `array([0, 1]), array([2, 0])` - which means `more_ships[0]` is within 200 pixels of `ships[2]`, and `more_ships[1]` is near `ships[0]`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I'm sorry but I've tried implementing this and I can't wrap my head around what you've written here - would you be able to demonstrate an example using a method like pygame.draw.line to draw a line between any two ships that have a distance of 200 pixels?

Comment: 200 pixels or less in both x and y axis*